# PHP Class and XML

Tags: php, class, oop

I learn something grade classes in PHP now I understand something is not the code looks like this

```
<?php
    class Shoutcast{

        private $host;
        private $port;
        private $username;
        private $password;
        private $post;

        public function Shoutcast ($host, $port, $username, $password, $post)
        {
            $this->host;
            $this->port;
            $this->username;
            $this->password;
            $this->post;
            $this->xml;

            $this->connect();
        }


        }
    }

?>
```

I call the class from

```
$shoutcast = new Shoutcast('IP', 'PORT', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'op=listdjs&seq=1234');
     foreach ($this->xml->data->djlist->dj as $dj) {

      echo "$dj->name";

     }
```

and get this error message ...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\klassen\shoutcast.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\klassen\shoutcast.php(33): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\klassen\shoutcast.php(19): Shoutcast->connect() #2 C:\xampp2\htdocs\klassen\shoutcast.php(41): Shoutcast->Shoutcast('81.169.216.4', '8200', 'admin', 'Uhu70007', 'op=listdjs&seq=...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\klassen\shoutcast.php on line 33
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm still learning and understand just probably the Syntext PHP is not for me just a hobbie,

the code reads the DJ of Shhoutcast2 from

Comment: `$this->host.'/api'` does not return XML. `var_dump($curl);` to see what it _does_ return. Also, look at `curl_error()`.

Comment: Inspect the returned string with `var_dump($curl);` Does it look like the expected well-formed XML? If so, you can call `simplexml_load_string()`.

Comment: Ah yes - you are not performing any operations on the values passed to `__construct()`. Assume you intended to do `$this->host = $host;` etc...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: `$data_is_url` defaults to `false`, so `new SimpleXMLElement($string);` & `simplexml_load_string($string);` are functionally equivalent, or am I missing something? And you're probably right about the constructor, just glanced over it here ;).

Comment: @Wrikken Didn't mean to say that `simplexml_load_string()` would behave differently, but I find it clearer & easier to understand for instantiation.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: OK, I can see that point indeed.

Comment: @user3123832 , since release of PHP 5.0 there is `__construct` method. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($this->xml->data->djlist->dj as $dj) {
```

Your problem is the call - you have to query the Class - not this

try

```
foreach ($shoutcast->xml->data->djlist->dj as $dj) {
```